# substr function displaying a blank page

Tags: php, web-scraping, substr

I am trying to use substr function in PHP for the below html string

```
<HR><CENTER><B>References <a href="aaaa">[Referenced By]</A></B></CENTER>       <HR>
         <CENTER><b>Documents</b></CENTER>
<TABLE WIDTH="100%"> <TR><TH scope="col" WIDTH="33%"></TH> <TH scope="col" WIDTH="33%"></TH> <TH scope="col" WIDTH="34%"></TH></TR> <TR> <TD ALIGN="left">
```

$html is the variable that includes the string above, and my code as below

```
$ints = strpos($html,"<b>Documents</b></CENTER>");
$ii=strlen("<b>Documents</b></CENTER>");

echo substr($html,$ints + $ii+2,7);
```

this is working very well with me and I got result

```
TABLE W
```

but when I tried to write the echo as below I have a blank page with no errors

```
echo substr($html,$ints + $ii,7);
```

any suggestion what is wrong? is the starting of the new line is the reason? appreciate your help and if you have any solution.

Comment: this only sample, I have a lot of formats, and using if function, just I am trying to write a simple code without the full codes, which is complicated.

Comment: You're not getting a blank page. You're probably getting a rendered HTML page that happens to contain `<TABLE`. Do a 'view source' to confirm.

Comment: this is correct, thank you, I didn't notice this before

Comment: @MarcB please add your answer, in order to select it and close this post, thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not getting a blank page. You're probably getting a rendered HTML page that happens to contain `<TABLE`. Do a 'view source' to confirm.